# Can I style my .doc file written from inside Java app. to be styled such as varied fonts & colours?

Tags: java, swing, styling, doc

I have built an application in Swing to create a resume from the input data from the users and I am writing all the data to a .doc file with some hard-coded text aligning, but I want it to look good, stylish. Is there any way I can from inside my Java program add styles to the text. I am using `printWriter` and `println()` method to write to file.

Comment: [JTextPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).

Comment: [more relevant links](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+swing+styles+text+component+jtextpane+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Comment: thats fine but when i write it to a file it would all be a plain text right!

Comment: If you write it as text, then yes, the file will contain nothing but text without any formatting information. There are libraries that assist reading and writing Word documents, but I am not familiar with them, nor do I know if there are EditorKits that allow direct translation of word document to TextPane-relevant information, and this is why I only commented and didn't answer. I think that you may benefit from doing some exhaustive Google searching, and then perhaps coming back with focused questions.

Comment: *"I am using `printWriter` and `println()` method to write to file."*  It is then likely that the `.doc` is really a plain text file with an (incorrect) `.doc` extension.  Use [Apache POI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-poi) to create MS Office files.  It would (I expect) have many options for styling, formatting and aligning the text.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Apache POI ,yes i have heard but don't know that it is exactly what i am looking for

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i will make sure next time thanks

Comment: No problem. I'm not your down-voter by the way, since I don't feel comfortable voting on questions that I don't consider myself to be an expert or journeyman on the subject.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  *"..I'm not your down-voter by the way.."*  Huh... I had not noticed that.  If the down voter would care to share their reasoning, I'd also like to know. OP *"..but don't know that it is exactly what i am looking for.."* an API used to read/write MS documents is very appropriate to writing a Word doc.  Perhaps it would be better to offer to write an RTF file.  A Rich Text File will allow setting colors and fonts to text, and can be handled (read/written) by existing Swing components (like `JTextPane` mentioned earlier).  But if a Word doc is actually required..

Comment: .. it will be necessary to use 3rd party APIs to create it.

Comment: thanks :),off to Apache POI tutorials